# Android Color Picker

Tags: java, android, colors, picker

I am looking for a Color Picker framework which can return color HEX on selection.

I have looked at [this](https://github.com/danielnilsson9/color-picker-view) wondering if there is some other library I can use.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try  this open source  projects that might help you

https://github.com/QuadFlask/colorpicker

Comment: links are not working anymore

Comment: This library also includes a nice color wheel and pallet picker: https://github.com/eltos/SimpleDialogFragments

Answer (score 44):

I know the question is old, but if someone is looking for a great new android color picker that use material design I have forked an great project from github and made a simple-to-use android color picker dialog.

This is the project: [Android Color Picker](https://github.com/Pes8/android-material-color-picker-dialog)

## Android Color Picker dialog

[image]

### HOW TO USE IT

#### Adding the library to your project

The aar artifact is available at the **jcenter** repository. Declare the repository and the
dependency in your `build.gradle`.

(root)

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

(module)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.pes.materialcolorpicker:library:1.0.2'
}
```

#### Use the library

Create a color picker dialog object

```
final ColorPicker cp = new ColorPicker(MainActivity.this, defaultColorR, defaultColorG, defaultColorB);
```

defaultColorR, defaultColorG, defaultColorB are 3 integer ( value 0-255) for the initialization of the color picker with your custom color value. If you don't want to start with a color set them to 0 or use only the first argument

Then show the dialog (when & where you want) and save the selected color

```
/* Show color picker dialog */
cp.show();

/* On Click listener for the dialog, when the user select the color */
Button okColor = (Button)cp.findViewById(R.id.okColorButton);

okColor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            
        /* You can get single channel (value 0-255) */
        selectedColorR = cp.getRed();
        selectedColorG = cp.getGreen();
        selectedColorB = cp.getBlue();
            
        /* Or the android RGB Color (see the android Color class reference) */
        selectedColorRGB = cp.getColor();

        cp.dismiss();
    }
});
```

That's all :)

Comment: awesome one buddy :D

Comment: Thanks :) If you have any suggestion tell me.

I needed it two weeks ago so I made it by myself, I hope it is helpful to someone else

Comment: @SimonePessotto setOnclicklistner  on buttonOk it give Null pointer exception.Help me.

Comment: @Clifford I'll check ... What did you do exactly ?

Comment: And also tell me wich version of android are you developing for

Comment: @Clifford did you try to set the listener before show the color picker? Because you can't, you need to show the color picker and after set the listener to the button. Btw open a new question maybe and paste some code :) I'm here if you need help

Comment: ohh ok... Thank you @SimonePessotto. ColorPicker is  simple and good one.Thank you again :)

Comment: It doesn't not work anymore. I can't add it to my project.

Comment: @DanishAjaib if you encountered any errors please open an issue on the Github project. Please also note that the answer is old and in the meantime the project has changed some API / function call

Comment: Please @SimonePessotto update the dependencies:
compile 'com.pes.materialcolorpicker:library:1.2.5'

Comment: @nicomonjelat what do you mean? Fell free to submit a pull-request if you want :)

Comment: @SimonePessotto, sorry. I meant to update the module dependencies in this answer. They are outdated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 17):

You can use the following code, it will give you same look as http://code.google.com/p/color-picker-view/

```
public class ColorPickerDialog extends Dialog {

public interface OnColorChangedListener {
    void colorChanged(String key, int color);
}

private OnColorChangedListener mListener;
private int mInitialColor, mDefaultColor;
private String mKey;

private static class ColorPickerView extends View {
    private Paint mPaint;
    private float mCurrentHue = 0;
    private int mCurrentX = 0, mCurrentY = 0;
    private int mCurrentColor, mDefaultColor;
    private final int[] mHueBarColors = new int[258];
    private int[] mMainColors = new int[65536];
    private OnColorChangedListener mListener;

    ColorPickerView(Context c, OnColorChangedListener l, int color,
            int defaultColor) {
        super(c);
        mListener = l;
        mDefaultColor = defaultColor;

        // Get the current hue from the current color and update the main
        // color field
        float[] hsv = new float[3];
        Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
        mCurrentHue = hsv[0];
        updateMainColors();

        mCurrentColor = color;

        // Initialize the colors of the hue slider bar
        int index = 0;
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Red (#f00) to pink
                                                    // (#f0f)
        {
            mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb(255, 0, (int) i);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Pink (#f0f) to blue
                                                    // (#00f)
        {
            mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb(255 - (int) i, 0, 255);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Blue (#00f) to light
                                                    // blue (#0ff)
        {
            mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb(0, (int) i, 255);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Light blue (#0ff) to
                                                    // green (#0f0)
        {
            mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb(0, 255, 255 - (int) i);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Green (#0f0) to yellow
                                                    // (#ff0)
        {
            mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb((int) i, 255, 0);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Yellow (#ff0) to red
                                                    // (#f00)
        {
            mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb(255, 255 - (int) i, 0);
            index++;
        }

        // Initializes the Paint that will draw the View
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        mPaint.setTextSize(12);
    }

    // Get the current selected color from the hue bar
    private int getCurrentMainColor() {
        int translatedHue = 255 - (int) (mCurrentHue * 255 / 360);
        int index = 0;
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {
            if (index == translatedHue)
                return Color.rgb(255, 0, (int) i);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {
            if (index == translatedHue)
                return Color.rgb(255 - (int) i, 0, 255);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {
            if (index == translatedHue)
                return Color.rgb(0, (int) i, 255);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {
            if (index == translatedHue)
                return Color.rgb(0, 255, 255 - (int) i);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {
            if (index == translatedHue)
                return Color.rgb((int) i, 255, 0);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {
            if (index == translatedHue)
                return Color.rgb(255, 255 - (int) i, 0);
            index++;
        }
        return Color.RED;
    }

    // Update the main field colors depending on the current selected hue
    private void updateMainColors() {
        int mainColor = getCurrentMainColor();
        int index = 0;
        int[] topColors = new int[256];
        for (int y = 0; y < 256; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
                if (y == 0) {
                    mMainColors[index] = Color.rgb(
                            255 - (255 - Color.red(mainColor)) * x / 255,
                            255 - (255 - Color.green(mainColor)) * x / 255,
                            255 - (255 - Color.blue(mainColor)) * x / 255);
                    topColors[x] = mMainColors[index];
                } else
                    mMainColors[index] = Color.rgb(
                            (255 - y) * Color.red(topColors[x]) / 255,
                            (255 - y) * Color.green(topColors[x]) / 255,
                            (255 - y) * Color.blue(topColors[x]) / 255);
                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int translatedHue = 255 - (int) (mCurrentHue * 255 / 360);
        // Display all the colors of the hue bar with lines
        for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
            // If this is not the current selected hue, display the actual
            // color
            if (translatedHue != x) {
                mPaint.setColor(mHueBarColors[x]);
                mPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
            } else // else display a slightly larger black line
            {
                mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
            }
            canvas.drawLine(x + 10, 0, x + 10, 40, mPaint);
            // canvas.drawLine(0, x+10, 40, x+10, mPaint);
        }

        // Display the main field colors using LinearGradient
        for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
            int[] colors = new int[2];
            colors[0] = mMainColors[x];
            colors[1] = Color.BLACK;
            Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, 50, 0, 306, colors, null,
                    Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
            mPaint.setShader(shader);
            canvas.drawLine(x + 10, 50, x + 10, 306, mPaint);
        }
        mPaint.setShader(null);

        // Display the circle around the currently selected color in the
        // main field
        if (mCurrentX != 0 && mCurrentY != 0) {
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.drawCircle(mCurrentX, mCurrentY, 10, mPaint);
        }

        // Draw a 'button' with the currently selected color
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setColor(mCurrentColor);
        canvas.drawRect(10, 316, 138, 356, mPaint);

        // Set the text color according to the brightness of the color
        if (Color.red(mCurrentColor) + Color.green(mCurrentColor)
                + Color.blue(mCurrentColor) < 384)
            mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        else
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawText(
                getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.settings_bg_color_confirm), 74,
                340, mPaint);

        // Draw a 'button' with the default color
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setColor(mDefaultColor);
        canvas.drawRect(138, 316, 266, 356, mPaint);

        // Set the text color according to the brightness of the color
        if (Color.red(mDefaultColor) + Color.green(mDefaultColor)
                + Color.blue(mDefaultColor) < 384)
            mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        else
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawText(
                getResources().getString(
                        R.string.settings_default_color_confirm), 202, 340,
                mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(276, 366);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            return true;
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        // If the touch event is located in the hue bar
        if (x > 10 && x < 266 && y > 0 && y < 40) {
            // Update the main field colors
            mCurrentHue = (255 - x) * 360 / 255;
            updateMainColors();

            // Update the current selected color
            int transX = mCurrentX - 10;
            int transY = mCurrentY - 60;
            int index = 256 * (transY - 1) + transX;
            if (index > 0 && index < mMainColors.length)
                mCurrentColor = mMainColors[256 * (transY - 1) + transX];

            // Force the redraw of the dialog
            invalidate();
        }

        // If the touch event is located in the main field
        if (x > 10 && x < 266 && y > 50 && y < 306) {
            mCurrentX = (int) x;
            mCurrentY = (int) y;
            int transX = mCurrentX - 10;
            int transY = mCurrentY - 60;
            int index = 256 * (transY - 1) + transX;
            if (index > 0 && index < mMainColors.length) {
                // Update the current color
                mCurrentColor = mMainColors[index];
                // Force the redraw of the dialog
                invalidate();
            }
        }

        // If the touch event is located in the left button, notify the
        // listener with the current color
        if (x > 10 && x < 138 && y > 316 && y < 356)
            mListener.colorChanged("", mCurrentColor);

        // If the touch event is located in the right button, notify the
        // listener with the default color
        if (x > 138 && x < 266 && y > 316 && y < 356)
            mListener.colorChanged("", mDefaultColor);

        return true;
    }
}

public ColorPickerDialog(Context context, OnColorChangedListener listener,
        String key, int initialColor, int defaultColor) {
    super(context);

    mListener = listener;
    mKey = key;
    mInitialColor = initialColor;
    mDefaultColor = defaultColor;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    OnColorChangedListener l = new OnColorChangedListener() {
        public void colorChanged(String key, int color) {
            mListener.colorChanged(mKey, color);
            dismiss();
        }
    };

    setContentView(new ColorPickerView(getContext(), l, mInitialColor,
            mDefaultColor));
    setTitle(R.string.settings_bg_color_dialog);

    }
}
```

Comment: @jRowan Can I ask how did you initialize the `Dialog` in your activity?

Comment: @Try_me34 in this link i explain it in an edit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22724899/understanding-color-picker-dialog/22726100#22726100

Comment: What a terrible code.. Using this really hurts.

Comment: If anyone from the future comes here, this is one class I created: https://github.com/carlosbar/AndroidColorPicker

Answer (score 14):

I ended up here looking for a HSV color picker that offered transparency and copy/paste of the hex value. None of the existing answers met those needs, so here's the library I ended up writing:

[HSV-Alpha Color Picker for Android](https://github.com/martin-stone/hsv-alpha-color-picker-android) (GitHub).

[HSV-Alpha Color Picker Demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rarepebble.colorpickerdemo) (Google Play).

I hope it's useful for somebody else.

[image: Color Picker Dialog]

Comment: This is a great color picker library.

Comment: Can we freely use this library in our commercial apps?

Comment: Basically, yes. (The license is in the GitHub repo -- Apache 2.0.)

Answer (score 8):

We have just uploaded AmbilWarna color picker to Maven:

https://github.com/yukuku/ambilwarna

It can be used either as a dialog or as a Preference entry.

[image]

Comment: No frills, easy to use.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another library:
https://github.com/eltos/SimpleDialogFragments

Features color wheel and pallet picker dialogs

[image]

[image]

#### Usage for HSV Color picker:

Add the library from maven and in your code just call:

```
SimpleColorWheelDialog.build()
                      .color(0xFFCF4747) // optional initial color
                      .alpha(true)
                      .show(Activity.this, COLOR_PICKER);
```

and to get the results let the Activity or fragment implement `OnDialogResultListener`:

```
@Override
public boolean onResult(@NonNull String dialogTag, int which, @NonNull Bundle extras) {
    if (COLOR_PICKER.equals(dialogTag) && which == BUTTON_POSITIVE){
        int color = extras.getInt(SimpleColorWheelDialog.COLOR);
        // ...
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want a fragment solution, I have made a fork of **android-color-picker** where **DialogFragment** is used and is re-created on configuration change. Here's the link: https://github.com/lomza/android-color-picker

Answer (score 1):

After some searches in the android references, the newcomer QuadFlask Color Picker seems to be a technically and aesthetically good choice. Also it has Transparency slider and supports HEX coded colors.

Take a look:
[QuadFlask Color Picker](https://github.com/QuadFlask/colorpicker)