# How to use a layout's background as a bitmap to convert X and Y to RGB values

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, android-framelayout

I have a layout with the color palette as the background.

[image]

Within the layout I added a smaller image as a thumb (which is resized using `@dimen` to make it smaller, really small, like a crosshair) which should move around as the user drag around the layout above:

[image]

How do I use the layout's background as a bitmap so I can use the following code:

```
f = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fl);
f.setOnTouchListener(flt);

iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);

View.OnTouchListener flt = new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            //int pixel = resizedbitmap.getPixel((int)x,(int) y); //the background of the layout goes here...

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (x<0) {
                    x = x + 10;
                    iv.setX(x);
                    iv.setY(y);
                }
                if (x>f.getWidth()) {
                    x = x - 10;
                    iv.setX(x);
                    iv.setY(y);
                }
                else {
                    iv.setX(x);
                    iv.setY(y);
                }
                // Write your code to perform an action on down
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (x<0) {
                    x = x + 10;
                    iv.setX(x);
                    iv.setY(y);
                    inRed = Color.red(pixel);
                    inBlue = Color.blue(pixel);
                    inGreen = Color.green(pixel);
                    Log.d("Colors","R:" +inRed +" G:" +inGreen+" B:" + inBlue);
                }
                if (x>f.getWidth()) {
                    x = x - 10;
                    iv.setX(x);
                    iv.setY(y);
                }
                else {
                    iv.setX(x);
                    iv.setY(y);
                }
                // Write your code to perform an action on contineus touch move
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Write your code to perform an action on touch up
                break;
        }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    };
```

The XML is:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/palette2"
    android:id="@+id/fl" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/esquare" />

</FrameLayout>
```

What I am looking to do is, create a color picker so as the user drags within the layout, the user is presented with the R G B values. Can anyone help me complete the codes?

Comment: you wan't to re size your layout ?

Comment: No... I only resize the thumb to use as cross hair.

Comment: :) so , what's the problem ?

Comment: The problem is how do I take the X and Y value and convert it to R G B?

Comment: what's this code return for you 
  int pixel = resizedbitmap.getPixel((int)x,(int) y);
??

Comment: How do I set a bitmap to a stretch the background of a layout??

Comment: try this in imageview layout 
android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: Its not an image... I want to get the layout background which is what I want to use to convert to bitmap. If I can do that than the issue will be resolved.

Comment: in think you need to make it as custom view and append to it all events and values

Comment: That's where I need help. I can create a custom view but how to add the thumb to it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the pixel with a line like the one you commented out.  Use BitMap's getPixel(x,y).  You need to keep a bitmap around for this.
2. getPixel() returns a color int, as you can see by checking http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html
   Actually, the documentation wrongly suggests that getPixel returns an android.graphics.Color object.  It does not.  It returns a color int argb.
3. get the components of the color int, c, by calls like this, as you can see by checking http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

   int alpha = Bitmap.alpha(c);

   int red = Bitmap.red(c);

Or you can do the bit ops yourself:

```
int alpha = c >>> 24;
int red = (c >>> 16) & 0xFF;
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have everything figured out except two things...1) how to get the bitmap of the background drawable of the layout and 2) how to keep the thumb within layout if the user drag outside the layout. Please help....

Comment: This post describes how to get a bitmap from a View (including a Layout):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android

Comment: To keep a draggable image within a certain region, you need to check the (x,y) position of every drag event, and stop moving the image in a direction that exceeds the region bounds.

Comment: I have been looking to do that and haven't made any progress... Any help? :)