# How to create color selector dialog?

Tags: android, themes, android-alertdialog, color-scheme

I want to add themes in my app. For this I want to add a color selector dialog, which will select the color and apply the particular theme.

How to add  color schemes to this?

Dialog like below image, colors in circle and arrow above which shows which color is selected.

[image]

How can I do this?
Thank you..

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980906/android-color-picker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summary:

1. Must have a list of color (c1, c2, ...) in value resource.
2. Must have a list of theme of corresponding color (th1, th2, ...) in style resource.
3. Create a color picker layout (`color_picker_dialog.xml`) for dialog: table layout or something that can display those colors
4. Create [custom dialog](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/) and set the content view of the dialog as `color_picker_dialog.xml`
5. Add `SetOnclickListener` to each element in the dialog to response to user click.